# python TypeError not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, typeerror

The program is meant to find the odd number in the string by checking if the number can be divided by 2 without a remainder, here is the code:

```
def iq_test(numbers): 
    for x in numbers.split():
       if x % 2 != 0:
          return x 

iq_test("1 2 3 4 5")
```

Here is the error i get when i run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 6, in <module>
File "python", line 3, in iq_test
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `if x % 2 != 0:` --> `if int(x) % 2 != 0:` (python thinks you're doing string formatting using the percent sign). Btw. you might want to do something else than `return` since it'll return after a single true `if` and, thus, only process the number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `%` (or more verbose [`operator.mod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mod)) on string literals, you're *attempting* to format:

```
>>> a = 'name'
>>> ('%s' % a) == 'name'
True
```

But you intend to use this on `int`, so you need to cast your string literals to integer:

```
if int(x) % 2 != 0
```

Then `mod` will attempt to find the modulus instead of attempting to format.

However, your function will return as soon as it finds the first odd number. If you intend to find all the odd numbers and not just the first, you can accumulate the odd numbers in a `list` and return the *joined* list:

```
def iq_test(numbers): 
    lst = []
    for x in numbers.split():
       if int(x) % 2 != 0:
           lst.append(x) 

    return ' '.join(lst)

iq_test("1 2 3 4 5")
# "1 3 5"
```

Another sleek alternative will be to try out [generator functions/expressions and yield](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a string, therefore the `%` resolves to string interpolation instead of modulo. Use `int(x) % 2 == 0`.

The error is raised, because 2 is the string formatting argument, but the string does not contain a matching amount of format specifiers.